# Android: Getting elements from a JSONArray without using standard for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist, arrays, json

So I have some code here that I'm trying to optimize and I cannot figure out how to go about making it at least into a for:each loop. Is there some sort of Iterator I could use that would let me do for each item in the Iterator?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static ArrayList<Community> parseRelatedCommunities(String response) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<Community> relCommunities = new ArrayList<Community>();
    Log.d(TAG, "parseRelatedCommunities:");
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int size;
        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
        responseObj = responseObj.getJSONObject(JSON_RESPONSE);
        JSONArray communitiesArray = responseObj.getJSONArray(JSON_COMMUNITY);
        Log.d(TAG, "parsing communities: " + communitiesArray.toString());
        size = communitiesArray.length();
            //this needs to change
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                JSONObject json = communitiesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                relCommunities.add(gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Community.class));}
        gson = null;
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON Parse Related Communities error: " + e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    finally
    {
        if(relCommunities.size() <= 0)
        {
        Community noCommunities = new Community();
        noCommunities.name = "No Available Communities";
        relCommunities.add(noCommunities);
        }
    }
    return relCommunities;
}
```

}

Comment: why do you need to optimize it so much? I would have thought if anything pulling the JSONObject json out of the for loop (then you only have one memory allocation) would be a better start than trying to optimize away the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to use a for:each loop, I just had to switch from using JSONArrays and JSONObjects to JsonArrays and JsonElements (note the subtle difference in case). Here's the updated parsing section:

```
JsonObject object = parser.parse(readerJS).getAsJsonObject();

        JsonObject responseObject = object.getAsJsonObject("response");

        JsonArray categoriesArray = responseObject.getAsJsonArray("badges");

        for (JsonElement je : categoriesArray) {
            newGameData.categories.add(gs.fromJson(je, CategoryData.class));
        }
```